# Optimisation hint for array of random numbers

Tags: c++, optimization, sse

To provide context, I'm working through [Programming Praxis Bingo Challenge](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/19/bingo/) and wanted to see how fast I could make this code run.

```
static void fisher_yates(T& source) {   
    const size_t len = source.size();
    for(size_t i = 1; i < len;++i) {
        std::swap(source[i],source[rand() % (i+1)]);
    }
}
std::array<int,25> generate_table() {
    std::array<int,25> bingo_grid;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 25;++i) {
        switch(i) {
        case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
            bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 1;
            break;
        case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
            bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 16;
            break;
        case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14:
            bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 31;
            break;
        case 15: case 16: case 17: case 18: case 19:
            bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 46;
            break;
        case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24:
            bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 61;
            break;
        }
    }
    bingo_grid[12] = 0;
    return bingo_grid;
}

bool is_bingoed(const std::array<int,25>& grid) { 
    // Check columns
    if(grid[0] == 0) {
        if(grid[1] == 0 && grid[2] == 0 && grid[3] == 0 && grid[4] == 0)
            return true;
        if(grid[0]  == 0 && grid[6]  == 0 && grid[18]  == 0 && grid[24]  == 0)
            return true;
        if(grid[5] == 0 && grid[10] == 0 && grid[15] == 0 && grid[20] == 0)
            return true;
    }
    if(grid[1] == 0) {
        if(grid[6]  == 0 && grid[11]  == 0 && grid[16]  == 0 && grid[21]  == 0)
            return true;
    }
    if(grid[2] == 0) {  
        if(grid[7] == 0 && grid[17]  == 0 && grid[22]  == 0)
            return true;
    }
    if(grid[3] == 0) {
        if(grid[8]  == 0 && grid[13]  == 0 && grid[18]  == 0 && grid[23]  == 0)
            return true;
    }
    if(grid[4] == 0) {
        if(grid[9]  == 0 && grid[14]  == 0 && grid[19]  == 0 && grid[24]  == 0)
            return true;
        if(grid[8]  == 0 && grid[16]  == 0 && grid[21]  == 0)
            return true;
    }
    if(grid[6] == 0) {
        if(grid[6]  == 0 && grid[7]  == 0 && grid[8]  == 0 && grid[9]  == 0)
            return true;
    }
    if(grid[12] == 0) {
        if(grid[10]  == 0 && grid[11]  == 0 && grid[13]  == 0 && grid[14] == 0)
            return true;
    }
    if(grid[18] == 0) {
        if(grid[15]  == 0 && grid[16]  == 0 && grid[17]  == 0 && grid[19]  == 0)
            return true;
    }   
    return false;
}

static bool mark_card(const int card,std::array<int,25>& bingo_grid) {
    for(auto &i : bingo_grid)
        if(card == i) {
            i = 0;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}

int play_game() {
    // Bingo is 5 columns, each column(n) is random permutation of 1-15*n
    // Fisher-Yates to generate random permutations

    // Create 500 playing cards
    const int max = 500;
    std::vector<std::array<int,25>> bingo_cards;
    bingo_cards.reserve(max);
    for(int i = 0; i<max;++i) {
        bingo_cards.push_back(generate_table());
        //display_bingo(bingo_cards[i]);
    }
    // Random shuffle 75 cards
    auto iter = boost::counting_range(1,76);
    std::vector<int> cards(std::begin(iter),std::end(iter));
    fisher_yates(cards);
    bool is_finished = false;
    int counter = 0;
    for(auto card : cards) {
        for(auto& playing_card : bingo_cards) {
            if(mark_card(card,playing_card)) {
                //display_bingo(playing_card);
                if(is_bingoed(playing_card))
                    return counter;
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
int bingo() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000;i++) {
        total+=play_game();
    }
    boost::singleton_pool<boost::pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(int)>::release_memory();
    return total / 10000;
}
```

The original version used a boost::multi_array to represent the grid. After profiling, I changed it to a std::array which got me a significant speed up. I then moved from using fisher_yates shuffle to generate bingo cards to using a random number generator.
Then finally I changed the is_bingoed test function to reduce the number of checks per call to speed up the game-over check.

All this has helped. Right now if I profile this code, the generate_table function takes up 72% of the time, mark_card() is 18%, and is_bingoed() about 6%. I'm looking for hints to see what can be done to improve the speed of either.

My first thought with is_bingoed() is to use the SSE intrinsics to do a compare with 0 (maybe use XOR?) but I don't have any ideas on the generate_table() or mark_car(). This is more of a self challenge for fun but wondered what others thought?

Current timing is it takes 4.6s on a 2Ghz Q6660 (down from 35s originally)

Comment: When you profile your code what percentage of `generate_table` is spent in `rand` ?

Comment: About 40% is spent in rand()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just focussing on your most expensive function, `generate_table`, you can simplify this part of the code and make it less branchy, which may help:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 25;++i) {
    switch(i) {
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
        bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 1;
        break;
    case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
        bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 16;
        break;
    case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14:
        bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 31;
        break;
    case 15: case 16: case 17: case 18: case 19:
        bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 46;
        break;
    case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24:
        bingo_grid[i] = rand() % 15 + 61;
        break;
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 25;++i) {
    int r = rand() % 15 + 1;
    bingo_grid[i] = r + (i / 5) * 15;
}
```

Beyond that I'd look at a faster rand() and also see if you can get rid of the divide and and modulo.

On a separate note, your algorithm may be flawed in that there is nothing to prevent duplicate numbers in bingo_grid.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the is_bingoed() method to use SSE instructions (using [Agner Fog's](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) library) and Paul R's generate_table() reduced the time to just 1.05s.  And using [Intel's fast_rand()](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-random-number-generator-on-the-intel-pentiumr-4-processor) function got it down to 0.38s.
So I thought I'd paste the code changes for others who might be interested.

```
static unsigned int g_seed;


//Used to seed the generator.
inline void fast_srand( int seed )
{
    g_seed = seed;
}


//fastrand routine returns one integer, similar output value range as C lib.
inline int fastrand()
{
    g_seed = (214013*g_seed+2531011);
    return (g_seed>>16)&0x7FFF;

}
bool is_bingoed(const std::array<int,25>& grid) { 
    // Check columns
    Vec8i vec(grid[0],grid[1],grid[2],grid[3],grid[4],0,0,0);
    Vec4i vec2(grid[6],grid[18],grid[24],0);
    Vec4i vec3(grid[5],grid[10],grid[15],20);
    Vec8i vec4(grid[1],grid[6],grid[11],grid[16],grid[21],0,0,0);
    Vec4i vec5(grid[2],grid[7],grid[17],grid[22]);
    Vec8i vec6(grid[3],grid[8],grid[13],grid[18],grid[23],0,0,0);
    Vec8i vec7(grid[4],grid[9],grid[14],grid[19],grid[24],0,0,0);
    Vec4i vec8(grid[8],grid[16],grid[21],grid[4]);
    Vec4i vec9(grid[6],grid[7],grid[8],grid[9]);
    Vec8i vec10(grid[12],grid[10],grid[11],grid[13],grid[14],0,0,0);
    Vec8i vec11(grid[18],grid[15],grid[16],grid[17],grid[19],0,0,0);
    if(horizontal_and(vec) && horizontal_and(vec2) && horizontal_and(vec3) && horizontal_and(vec4) &&
        horizontal_and(vec5) && horizontal_and(vec6) && horizontal_and(vec7) && horizontal_and(vec8)) {
            return false;
    }
    if(horizontal_and(vec9) && horizontal_and(vec10) && horizontal_and(vec11)) {
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```